# I'm having problems trying to insert a varying number of values in a column, python-sql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-innodb-cluster, python-sql

Im new to sql, I have been trying to make a function that will allow creation of new columns and to fill it.

Its been giving these two errors:

- Failed executing the operation; Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement - for the first if
- Failed executing the operation; Not enough parameters for the SQL statement - for the elif

Anyother changes I should make or adivce are all welcome

````
def alter_table():
    tbl_name = input("Which table whould you like to edit:")
    opr = int(input("Do you want to ADD or DROP a column, Type: \n1: ADD \n2: DROP\n"))
    if opr == 1:
        
        name = input("What will this column be called: ")
        typ = int(input("What type of information will be stored in this column, Type: \n1: ONLY Numbers \n2: Letters and Numbers\n"))
        if typ == 1:
            cur.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD {} float".format(tbl_name,name))

        
            input_list = (input("Enter the values you want to store seperated by spaces")).split()
            value_list = [(int(i),)for i in input_list]
            
            n = "%d"*len(input_list)
            n_param = ','.join(n[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(n), 2))
            query = "INSERT INTO {}({}) VALUES ({}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {} = VALUES({})".format(tbl_name,name,n_param,tbl_name,tbl_name)
            cur.executemany(query, value_list)
        elif typ == 2:
            n_char = int(input("Maximum character limit for this column: "))
            cur.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD {} VARCHAR({})".format(tbl_name,name,n_char))

        
            input_list = (input("Enter the values you want to store seperated by spaces")).split()
            value_list = [(i,)for i in input_list]
            
            n = "%s"*len(input_list)
            n_param = ','.join(n[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(n), 2))
            query = "INSERT INTO {}({}) VALUES ({}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {} = VALUES({})".format(tbl_name,name,n_param,tbl_name,tbl_name)
            cur.executemany(query, value_list)

    elif opr == 2:
        name = input("Which column would you like to drop: ")
        cur.execute("ALTER TABLE {} DROP COLUMN {}".format(tbl_name,name))
        print("Column Deleted")```
````

Comment: Please, post your code as text. So others can copy your code instead of retyping it.

Comment: Welcome.. No image please.. paste your code as text.

Comment: Ah got it, this was my first time posting. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It is also useful to print the exact error you get, including traceback information to identify the statement that is actually failing.

I would, however, strongly advise against taking arbitrary string input and inserting it into a SQL query.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python.

Comment: The stuff you do with `n = "%d"*len(input_list)` is overly complicated. Just use `n_param = ','.join(['%s'] * len(input_list))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for inserting multiple rows is wrong. You're generating

```
VALUES ((row1), (row2), ...)
```

but it should be

```
VALUES (row1), (row2), ...
```

You don't need to do all the looping and joining yourself. `cur.executemany()` will automatically repeat the `VALUES` lists for you.

```
            input_list = (input("Enter the values you want to store seperated by spaces")).split()
            value_list = [(int(i),)for i in input_list]
            
            query = f"INSERT INTO {tbl_name} ({name}) VALUES (%s)"
            cur.executemany(query, value_list)
```

There's no point in using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, since you're not inserting into the key column of the table. So there's no way to tell if a row is a duplicate.

Comment: With this, it is creating new rows to add the values. It is possible to have it fill the column from the top?

Comment: There's no built-in ordering of MySQL rows. You need some way of indicating which rows each value should be updated into.